# Conditionally running a function on a row based on values in another column using a function

Tags: r

I'm looking at writing an R function that operates on each row of a dataframe. The function needs to perform an adjustment calculation on a `measurement` column that corresponds to mass/volume of a food or drink where the adjustment calculation differs depending on if it's a food or a drink, and if it's a drink what kind of drink is it.

I've written the following small example that shows roughly the code structure I have.

```
df <- data.frame(type = c("food","drink","drink"), drink_type = c(NA, "ice-cream","soft-drink"), measurement = c(100, 50, 60))

adjuster <- function(row) {
    adjusted_val <- switch(tolower(row[['type']]),
            "food" = row[['measurement']] * 1.2,
            "drink" = drink_converter(row),
            stop(paste0("adjuster: Unable to determine food type from value: ",row['type']," from `type` column"))
    )

    return(adjusted_val)
}

drink_converter <- function(row) {
        adjusted_val <- switch(tolower(row[['drink_type']]),
            "ice-cream" = row[['measurement']] * 1.09,
            "soft-drink" = row[['measurement']] * 1.03,
            stop(paste0("adjuster: Unable to determine food type from value: ",row['type']," from `type` column"))
    )

    return(adjusted_val)
}
```

This behaves one row at a time.

```
> adjuster(df[1,])
[1] 120
> adjuster(df[2,])
[1] 54.5
> adjuster(df[3,])
[1] 61.8
```

But i'm unsure of how to apply it across the whole dataframe in one go. Using `apply` does not behave correctly because, as my dataframe contains characters using `apply` coerces everything to characters and you get the following error:

```
> apply(df, 1, adjuster)
Error in row[["measurement"]] * 1.2 : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Now I could handle this by wrapping every `row[['measurement']]` with `as.numeric` and would get the behaviour I want. However, I want to know if that is sensible or if there is a neater way in base R to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
   mutate(out = adjuster(pick(everything()))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  type  drink_type measurement   out
  <chr> <chr>            <dbl> <dbl>
1 food  <NA>               100 120  
2 drink ice-cream           50  54.5
3 drink soft-drink          60  61.8
```

---

`apply` with `MARGIN = 1`, converts to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single class.  Instead use `lapply` on the sequence and subset

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), \(i) adjuster(df[i,]))
[[1]]
[1] 120

[[2]]
[1] 54.5

[[3]]
[1] 61.8
```

Comment: ```cbind(df,  out = unlist(lapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) adjuster(df[i,]))))``` to get the same results as the `dplyr` solution.

Comment: @akrun the syntax you've got here with lapply, in particular `\(i)` can you explain how that works and should that be compatible with R 3.6.1?